# Mapping Google domain with AWS Route 53

Tags: amazon-route53

1. I have registered a domain "javacloud.org" in domains.google.com.
2. Created hosted zone in AWS Route 53 for javacloud.org
3. Name servers generated in step 2 are copied to javacloud.org DNS custom name servers.
4. I have setup jenkins on AWS EC2 and created Record Set in above hosted zone with A type record and name is jenkins.javacloud.org with EC2 Public IP.
5. I made sure port is open in EC2 security groups.
6. Not able to access jenkins.javacloud.org:port

Question -
Is it mandatory that www.javacloud.org should also be accessible over internet?

[my route 53 setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Ade8.png)

[custom name servers in google domain](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tK0Bo.png)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All the above mentioned steps are correct. AWS Route 53 took time almost a day and I am able to access my sub-domain.